# Load javascript function after other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions. I'd like `moduleList()` to load AFTER `reloadModules()`:

```
reloadModules();
moduleList();

function reloadModules() {
    $.get(v2_settings_url + 'v2_nav/', null, function(responseText) {
        $('#dock ul').html(responseText).parent().fadeIn();
    });
    $.get(v2_settings_url + 'v2_edit_bar_nav/', null, function(responseText) {
        var target = $('#edit-nav-bar-settings-div');
        target.html(responseText);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then simply pass the `moduleList();` function as a **callback** function (a parameter) to the `reloadModules();` function. Then chain your ajax calls and the `moduleList();` function this way:

```
reloadModules(moduleList);

function reloadModules(moduleList) {
    $.get(v2_settings_url + 'v2_nav/', null, function(responseText) {
        $('#dock ul').html(responseText).parent().fadeIn();
        $.get(v2_settings_url + 'v2_edit_bar_nav/', null, function(responseText){
            var target = $('#edit-nav-bar-settings-div');
            target.html(responseText);
            moduleList();
        });
    });
};
```

Now, in simple words, you're telling the browser to:

1. Execute `reloadModules` function, while passing it the `moduleList` function.
2. Get something from server
3. If you got it successfully, get something else from server
4. If you got it successfully, run the `moduleList` function

Answer (score 1):

call moduleList(); at the end of reloadModules(); and call reloadModules() where you want to call both !
Hope this helps.